# Does Android provide an API for determining weekend days that is locale-aware?

Tags: android, calendar, locale

I want to provide some styling to an app that is aware of work days and weekends, but I need it to be locale-aware. I'm aware of `Calendar#getFirstDayOfWeek`, but this only returns the first day of the week, not the first day of the work week.

For example, with English(Canada) `Calendar#getFirstDayOfWeek` returns `Calendar.SUNDAY`, which is the first day of our week. Our work week starts on `Calendar.MONDAY`, and our weekend days are `Calendar.SATURDAY` and `Calendar.SUNDAY`.

In English(United Kingdom), `Calendar#getFirstDayOfWeek` returns `Calendar.MONDAY`, and the first day of their work-week is Monday. Their weekend days are `Calendar.SATURDAY` and `Calendar.SUNDAY`.

Things get tricky for locales like Hebrew. The first day of their week is `Calendar.SUNDAY`, but instead of the first day of their work week being `Calendar.MONDAY`, it's `Calendar.SUNDAY`. Their weekend days are `Calendar.FRIDAY` and `Calendar.SATURDAY`. Egypt is the same.

Iran only has one weekend day, `Calendar.FRIDAY`.

Is there any method in Android to determine weekend days? We have some logic in place that covers most Western cases, but it's fragile, and a locale-aware platform API would be ideal, but I'm not aware of one.

Please note, I am not asking for a recommendation on some "best" library or anything of the sort. I'm asking if any such locale data exists on the Android platform at all, and if so, what API calls exist to access this data.

Comment: Curious about the -1 vote on the question? Did I not do something correctly when asking? I've done plenty of research, asked a clear question, and there's no need for sample code.

Comment: Oh, so 2 negative votes with no explanation. Yeah, thanks for that.

Comment: Presumably, you should use any such API only to guess the default settings, and let the user pick something else in case their locale wasn't actually a good indication of their workweek ...

Comment: That capability is already in place, it's the locale default setting that is causing problems for users in some of these regions.

Comment: This question is perfectly fine and not off topic.

Comment: Good question. You could possibly parse (or copy) the list from this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend. It has the weekend days for each country (I believe that all the others are just default Mon-Fri work days, but haven't checked)

Comment: The raw data is available from the Unicode CLDR supplementary data at http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/supplementalData.xml (search for weekend)
I wanted to avoid loading and keeping track of new locale data, as that means I would have to maintain this (likely quite stable) data in my app going forward. Alas, this seems to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are newly released snapshot and fence APIs in Awareness API for your use-case for a locale-aware API for time.

Please take a look at [Awareness.SnapshotApi.getTimeIntervals](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/awareness/SnapshotApi.html#getTimeIntervals(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) which returns a TimeIntervalsResult. You can call getTimeIntervals() method to return an object that has information about the properties of the current time at current locale (specifically the weekend and holidays that you have asked for).

For example, the following code snippet checks if it is a weekend at the device's locale at the time of the snapshot api call.

```
Awareness.SnapshotApi.getTimeIntervalsmGoogleApiClient)
    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<TimeIntervalsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull TimeIntervalsResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not get the time intervals");
                return;
            }
            if (result.getTimeIntervals().hasTimeInterval(
                TimeFence.TIME_INTERVAL_WEEKEND)) {
                // do your custom action, this means it is weekend at the 
                // device locale at this time
            }
        }
```

If you'd like your app to get a callback on the next weekend or holiday at the device locale, you can use the new TimeFence Api [inTimeInterval()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/awareness/fence/TimeFence.html#inTimeInterval(int)). For example, borrowing the code snippet from the developer docs,

```
// Create TimeFence
AwarenessFence weekendHolidayFence = Awareness.or(
    TimeFence.inTimeInterval(TimeFence.TIME_INTERVAL_WEEKEND),
    TimeFence.inTimeInterval(TimeFence.TIME_INTERVAL_HOLIDAY))

Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(
    mGoogleApiClient,
    new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
        .addFence("fenceKey", weekendHolidayFence, myPendingIntent)
        .build())
    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Fence was successfully registered.");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Fence could not be registered: " + status);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks you, this looks perfect