# How do I determine which days are weekdays vs. weekend in Android?

Tags: android, locale

Qt/Qlocale has a weekdays() method which gives you the week-days for a locale.

Android only seems to have the `Calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek()` method which doesn't help - en_GB and en_US have Monday and Sunday as the first day of the week in calendars respectively, but both locales define Saturday/Sunday as the weekend.

A similar question was asked, but it was put on hold: [Does Android provide an API for determining weekend days that is locale-aware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32403889/does-android-provide-an-api-for-determining-weekend-days-that-is-locale-aware)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use ICU4J library http://site.icu-project.org and call getWeekData() on the calendar -> http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/Calendar.html#getWeekData()

This library supports Persian(Jalali) and Arabic(Hijri, Hijri-civil) calendars and many others.

```
Calendar.getInstance(new ULocale("fa_IR@calendar=persian"))
Calendar.getInstance(new ULocale("ar_IQ@calendar=islamic-civil"))
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(new ULocale("en_GB@calendar=gregorian"))

c.getFirstDayOfWeek()
c.getWeekData().weekendOnset // weekend start
c.getWeekData().weekendCease // weekend end
```

Answer (score 0):

Won't [this do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26598845/1715829):

```
Date d = new Date();
int dayOfWeek = d.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Comment: the OP is asking about how to know which days of the week are weekend days. This answer does not help.

Comment: But he states that: "both locales define Saturday/Sunday as the weekend" and this lets him determine if the day is a Saturday/Sunday

Comment: good point. I was refering to the other question, which mentions weekend day in Iran.

Comment: I should have emphasized that this should work across locales - where the weekend may be completely different (Friday/Saturday).

Answer (score 0):

A smaller alternative to ICU4J is using my library [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A). Example for localized weekend queries:

```
Locale yemen = new Locale("ar", "YE");
Weekmodel model = Weekmodel.of(yemen);
System.out.println(
    "Weekend: " + model.getStartOfWeekend() + " - " + model.getEndOfWeekend()
); // Weekend: THURSDAY - FRIDAY

PlainDate today = SystemClock.inLocalView().today();
System.out.println(today.isWeekend(yemen));
```

The source of the underlying data are based on CLDR (same as in ICU4J).

Answer (score 0):

You question seems to point to this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32403889/does-android-provide-an-api-for-determining-weekend-days-that-is-locale-aware) already. Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42284052/7477355). Note: The API does not give you the weekdays, but enables you to know if it is a weekday / holiday etc at the time of an API call at device location.

If that post answers your question fully, please consider marking your question a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have the day of the week, you can always determine if its a weekday/weekend using a simple switch or HashMap ?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
Date d = new Date();
String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(d);
switch(dayOfTheWeek){
    case "Mon":
    case "Tue":
    case "Wed":
    case "Thu":
    case "Fri":
        System.out.println("Weekday");
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Weekend");
        break;
}
```

Comment: But what if my active locale is an Arabic or Hebrew one, with a different definition of weekends? I would want this to work across all locales, obviously.